# Branch table in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I try to do a branch table in assembly 8086.

I wrote it:

```
    org 100h                       

    ; START THE PROGRAM

    mov si, 1
    jmp cs:table[si]

    table dw C1, C2, C3

C1:
    add bx, 1
    jmp EXIT

C2:
    add bx, 2
    jmp EXIT

C3:
    add bx, 3
    jmp EXIT
C4:  
    add bx, 4
    jmp EXIT

; EXIT PRORGRAM   
EXIT:
    mov ah, 0
    int 16h
    ret
```

The code not working, It's jump to the incorrect label.

Someone can give me example or fix my code ?

Comment: Recall that each entry in the table is two bytes long, thus the index must be multiplied by 2 before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be careful that

```
jmp cs:table[si]
```

actually is a mangled version of

```
jmp cs:[table + si]
```

It is not an array indexing.
The assembly language has no types, to avoid confusion don't use such an unorthodox syntax.

---

Suppose `table` starts at 1000h. Then

[image: Table in memory at 1000h]

With `SI = 1` the offset to jump to is taken at 1000h + 1 = 1001h.
The WORD at that location occupies 1001h and 1002h, thus it crosses *C1* and *C2*.

Using the index directly to access an array is a comfort not available in assembly, we need to scale the index based on the size of the items.
In this case each item is a WORD, 2 bytes, so the index must be scaled by 2.

```
Index    Scaled index    Address accessed
 0            0             1000h
 1            2             1002h
 2            4             1004h
```

Thus

```
 mov si, 1
 shl si, 1         ;Scale index, SI = SI*2^1 = SI*2
 jmp cs:table[si]
```

or better, if the index is known at "compile time"

```
 mov si, 2         ;Use scaled index directly
 jmp cs:table[si]
```

Comment: Nice answer and +1 for the graphic!